# Having trouble with capturing dynamically updated cart information for the dataLayer in Shopify when adding/removing quantities or products

Tags: ajax, shopify, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm using this script that has helped me as a starting template to capture events within Shopify to push to GTM: https://github.com/TechnicalWebAnalytics/dataLayer-shopify/blob/master/dataLayer-allPages.js

The problem is that even though it can detect Add to Cart or Remove from Cart, it does cannot detect quantities that were added or removed or items that were removed. The only time it can detect anything is when you add a product to the cart from the Product page.

I'm trying to see how I can use the cart.js https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api script to pull quantity updates or product removals but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

Looking for some pointers.

Comment: Are you trying to track this using ecommerce or just basic events? Can you post screenshots of the GA events you're talking about?

Comment: They aren't for GA. They are dataLayer events for GTM.

Comment: At the moment I'm modifying the code to detect cart delta but the problem is their cart global variable keeps showing a quantity of 1 so I can't create an accurate delta.